# I am getting memory errors though I dont rule memory manually in c++

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, free

I am trying to find the most bright point in image and make some kind "map of brightness" with function below. It works fine with one image but when I am trying to launch function for all images in directory it makes 19 iterations and then crushes with different memory errors.

I use Qt Creator 4.5. based on Qt 5.10 with Open cv library

```
free(): corrupted unsorted chunks

free(): invalid next size (normal)

malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size
```

I understand that I have memory problems but can't find where I did it. I am new in programming and didn't use memory functions in this program.

Function where problem appears. It crushes in a line with `convertTo()` usually.

```
cv::Mat Plot::statistic(const std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> &kp, const size_t dist, cv::Mat output_size) {

cv::Mat result = cv::Mat::zeros(output_size.size(), CV_32F); 

for(int i = 0, imax= kp.size(); i < imax; ++i) {
    cv::KeyPoint curr_kp=kp[i];
    for(size_t m = curr_kp.pt.x - dist/2 ; m < curr_kp.pt.x + dist/2; ++m)
        for(size_t n = curr_kp.pt.y - dist/2; n < curr_kp.pt.y + dist/2; ++n)
            if(abs(cv::norm(cv::Point2f(m,n) - curr_kp.pt)) < dist/2)
                result.at<float>(n,m) += 255.f/kp.size();
}

double maxVal=1;
cv::Point point_max;
cv::minMaxLoc(result,NULL,&maxVal,NULL,&point_max);
result.convertTo(result,CV_8U,255.f/maxVal);
return result;
}
```

How I'm calling it:

```
for(int i=2,imax=plot_analyse.size();i<imax;i++) {
    QString curr_img=input_image.absoluteFilePath(plot_analyse[i]);
    QString output_path=output_dir+"/pltnst_"+curr_img.section("/",-1); //Setting output folder

    mt_make.Make_analysis(curr_img,5000); //Finding up to 5000 keypoints on image
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> original_kp = mt_make.Keypoints(); //Make a variable for keypints

    if (original_kp.empty()) {continue; }
    cv::Mat output_mat=Do.Open_image(curr_img.toStdString()); //Opening current image
    output_mat=make_maps.statistic(original_kp,100,output_mat); //Calling function
    cv::imwrite(output_path.toStdString(),output_mat); //Saving ready brightness map
}
```

Input folder has 500+ gray images with 1000x1000 resolution. I expect that all this images will have brightness maps in output folder and points of max brightness for each.

Comment: Check the values of `n` and `m` in your loops, they may be out of bounds.

Comment: Have you considered running with valgrind to identify where your memory corruption first occurs? If that's not available for your platform, you'll have to tell us what that platform is to get more useful responses.

Comment: Error like that are very typical when going out of bounds. Use memory debugger tools (such as the mentioned Valgrind) to help you find the problem.